# Is there a way to list all jobs of Jenkins in a shell script that will be run as a Jenkins job

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am writing shell commands as a build step for Jenkins job

Is there a way to write a script that list all Jenkins jobs

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below reference. This seems to answer your question
Ref: [Jenkins CLI List-Jobs with folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869765/jenkins-cli-list-jobs-with-folders)